# How to get all orders in bigcommerce API 3

Tags: bigcommerce

Hi I am using java to call rest api of Bigcommerce. How to get all orders from BIg commerce in api V3.

I know for V2. But I could not find the same in V3.I want to get all orders without providing order id.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't currently a v3 equivalent for the v2 Orders endpoint. In v3 you can get transaction/payment data, but not the full order. We do have plans to build out the orders resource on the v3 API in the future.

In the meantime, best practice is to use v3 for resources that are available through v3, but use v2 for any resources that are still on v2 only (like Orders). The API is designed with interoperability in mind, and both versions of the API can be used within the same application.

Comment: So when on the BigCommerce dev site it says v3 is "fully backward-compatible with v2", this is completely untrue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not fully backward-compatible? If you have a product created with the v2 API and then you do things to it with the v3 product API, it will still work, so it's backward compatible. But many v2 resources don't yet have a v3 equivalent to be backwards-compatible with (like orders, which exist only on v2). There wasn't a v2 version of transaction/payment API, so that's totally new on v3.

Comment: I took backwards compatible to mean the v2 calls all work in v3. That is not the case however. The BigCommerce docs are a little bit convoluted which leads to some extra confusion, but it does become clear pretty quickly that my assumption that you could make v2 calls against the v3 endpoints isn't true. Every other time I've seen a "backwards compatible" API it means that the old calls worked against the new endpoints. But I may be in the minority in thinking this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying--I can see where you're coming from, and we can look at making that more explicit in the docs.

Comment: @KarenWhite thanks for clarifying this.  Any updates on a v3 Orders endpoint?  It's been almost 2 years since you posted this.  Couldn't v3 be a simple pass through to v2 should that end point not exist? It is a bummer to have to support v2 and v3 api calls in the same code set.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is a little late, but I thought I'd pass along how I got this to work just now. The part that doesn't seem to be conveyed very clearly is that the v2 API is available for stores that are required to use the v3 API -- you just have to use the v3 authentication in your request.

A v2 request uses (User, Password) in the basic authorization header, and in my case, for an existing v2 store, I use this URL:

https://www.mystore.com/api/v2/orders/78225

to get an order (where mystore is the real name).

A v3 request uses (X-Auth-Client, X-Auth-Token) in the header, and in my case, for a new v3 store, I use this URL:

https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/mystorehash/v2/orders/722003

to get an order (where mystorehash is the store_hash that the BC documentation talks about).